# How to create a macro based template?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, vba

Is it possible to add macro in jrxml when exporting to excel?

I am not able found any documentation, the only thing I can find is this question on JasperSoft community, [Excel macro and pivot tables](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530936/excel-macro-and-pivot-tables).

Comment: @AlexK why not pass a nice answer ;)?

Answer (score 2):

The *MS Excel Macro* can be added from external file with *Macro* (of *MS Excel* type)  with help of [***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.macro.template***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.macro.template) report's property.

The *Macro* of *xltm* or *xlsm* types can be used.

#### Example

Let's try to add simple *Macro* for adding comment for active cell.
This *Macro* will be stored at *macro.xlsm* file.

The content of *Macro* (example*):

```vbnet
Sub add_comment()
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim str As String
    On Error Resume Next

    str = "Value: " + ActiveCell.Text
    Set cmt = ActiveCell.Comment
    If cmt Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.AddComment _
        Text:=str
        Set cmt = ActiveCell.Comment
    End If

    With cmt
        .Shape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
        .Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
        .Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 8
        .Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Shape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Shape.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Shape.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(58, 82, 184)
        .Shape.Fill.OneColorGradient msoGradientDiagonalUp, 1, 0.23
    End With

    SendKeys "+{F2}"  'opens comment for editing
End Sub
```

The *jrxml* file (report's template) will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Macro sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.macro.template" value="macro.xlsm"/>
    <title>
        <band height="158">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Long title]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="595" height="128"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Some text. This is a sample of using Macros]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

We are using **net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.macro.template** property for including script from our Macro's template to the generated report.

#### Output result

We can generate report of MS Excel format at *Jaspersoft Studio*:

[image: Exporting report at JSS]

After opening generated *xls* file we can run embedded *Macro*:

[image: Running Macro at Excel]

As the result of running *Macro* the new colored comment was created:

[image: Created comment at Excel file]

---

More information can be found at [Advanced Excel Features](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures) post.